# What does this arrow in cmd mean

Tags: c, cmd

I'm writing a program which takes input and outputs it one word per line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    
    while( (c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if( c != ' ')
            putchar(c);
        else
            putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

The program stops when it encounters the `EOF` character. When I input something like "Hello World^Z" (I am using Windows) I get the following output:

```
C:\Coding\C>a
Hello World^Z
Hello
World→
```

And it still waits for me to input something. What does the `→` symbol mean?

Comment: It means the `^Z` character (which is why it is still looking for input). You haven't actually marked EOF. On Windows, with line-buffered input, you can only use ctrl-Z to mark end of input *at the beginning of a line*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel well when I entered `Hello World`, I didn't press enter but pressed ctrl-Z. I didn't write "^Z" manually.

Comment: Karl knows that. The arrow output is the corresponding character emitted by the terminal. Characters in the range 0..31 might either perform an action ("control character") or show some glyph. Others might be card suits, smileys etc.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. On Windows, you must press ctrl-Z **as the first thing on the line** (i.e., immediately after pressing enter), and then press enter again.

Comment: https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/ is excellent reading and will hopefully clear up some misconceptions about EOF.